# Create Calendar in Sharepoint programmatically using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, calendar

How to Create a calendar list in SHarepoint using CSOM?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am creating calendar list on button click event using JavaScript.

Using **SP.ListTemplateType.events** template type you can create Calendar list.

You can below code inside content editor web part.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="createList()">Click here to Create a List</button>
```

**Code:**

```
<script>  
function createList()   
{  
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();  
    listCreationInfo.set_title('CalendarList');  
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.events);  
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);  
    clientContext.load(oList);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),   
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)  
);  
}  

function onQuerySucceeded()   
{  
    var result = oList.get_title() + ' created.';  
    alert(result);  
}  

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)   
{  
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +   
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: @spStacker, Please mark this answer as accepted, if you find this helpful  for you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code.

**Code to create a Calendar list in SPO Site using CSOM**

```
internal static void CreateSPList()
{
    Console.Write("Enter Username: ");
    string Username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Password: ");
    SecureString Password = GetConsoleSecurePassword();

    string siteUrl = "your site url";

    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, Password);

    ListCollection lists = ctx.Web.Lists;

    ListCreationInformation newList = new ListCreationInformation()
    {
        TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Events,
        Title = "NewCalendar",
        Description = "testing"
    };

    lists.Add(newList);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

**Code to generate secure password for SPO site**

```
private static SecureString GetConsoleSecurePassword()
{
    SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            pwd.RemoveAt(pwd.Length - 1);
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
        else
        {
            pwd.AppendChar(i.KeyChar);
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }
    return pwd;
}
```